# Express Handlebars custom Path

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, handlebars.js

my question is how can i have custom folders in express

my situation is this, i want to have the logic that if i have an specific name in my database i want that my css and js paths change before they get rendered

on default my path in express is

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

but if the user "spartan" gets called the main css path under public should change to /spartan/css/file.xyz

in this snipped from my handlebars template i've tried that

```
{{#each site.cssFiles}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.name}}/css/{{this}}.css" />
{{/each}}
```

on this example the result is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

but why? And how do i can get my target logic implementet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exit the scope of the current handlebars block like this :

```
{{#each site.cssFiles}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{../site.name}}/css/{{this}}.css" />
{{/each}}
```

By doing so handlebars will render whichever you have provided as `site.name` from your `res.render` method.

Comment: tried, in the html the link is as it should, but i dont get how the folder gets released to the client

Cannot GET /spartan/css/main.css

did i miss something?

Comment: This sounds like another question, regarding express static handler.